# Centering chapter name in table of content

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters

With this example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

I have `.toc` like this:
[image]
How I can have `.toc` like this
[image]
is there any way I can do that?

Comment: Please confirm that you don't want to show the page numbers associated with level-0 (chapter) entries in the ToC.

Comment: I want all chapter name come in center with no page number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following TeX code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@chapter[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\z@
    \addpenalty\@secpenalty
    \addvspace{1.0em \@plus\p@}%
    \setlength\@tempdima{1.8em}%
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      \leavevmode \bfseries
      \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
      \hskip -\leftskip
      \hfil#1\nobreak\hfil \nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{}\par
    \endgroup
  \fi}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks , In my oroginal table of content it wrote : chapter one bla bla, but now it wrote 1:bla bla

Comment: this part stops working : https://beepaste.io/view/0I3bHJ

Comment: how I can  replace chapter number to for **example chapter one Heading on level 0**